# Change font on highlighted text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the font when I highlight a text in the textarea. The function below changes the whole font in the textarea, rather than the text I want to change.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>E-commerce Website</title>
        <script>          
            function selectFont() {
                document.getElementById("note_header").style.fontFamily = "cursive";
            }
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <select id="select_font" onchange="selectFont()">
            <option>Select a font</option>
            <option>Cursive</option>
        </select>
        <textarea id="note_header">Title</textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing font of text within the Textarea won't work but will work for other properties like color, cursor etc.

A workaround is to use a content editable `<div>`. You can get the selected text with `window.getSelection` and then wrap with a `<span>`, after you can apply the style to span's content. As shown below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>E-commerce Website</title>
    <script>          
        function selectFont() {
            selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
            NoteHeader  = document.getElementById("note_header");
            EditedText = NoteHeader.innerText.replace(selectedText, 
                             `<span style="font-family: cursive">${selectedText} </span>`);
            NoteHeader.innerHTML = EditedText;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
   Highlight text and change font <br>
    <select id="select_font" onchange="selectFont()">
        <option>Select a font</option>
        <option>Cursive</option>
    </select>
    <div contenteditable="true" id="note_header" 
        style="width:200px; height:200px; border: 1px solid #ccc">
        Some Content
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to achieve your goal, but you could use the CSS pseudo element [`::selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection) to give the selected text some properties. Sadly the `font-family` can't be changed with this, but if you only want to highlight it in some way the properties you can change are:

- color
- background-color
- cursor
- caret-color
- outline and its longhands
- text-decoration and its associated properties
- text-emphasis-color
- text-shadow

```css
#note_header::selection {
  color: red;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="note_header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</textarea>
```